# Imprimir tabla con PHP

Tags: php, html, json, table

Tengo este código con el cual deseo mostrar unos datos de un JSON en una tabla, mi problema es que en la pantalla solo se imprimen las celdas de cabecera, y ahora que lo noto el link para volver tampoco se muestra.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost/060522/eliminar.php" method="post">
        <p>Para eliminar una materia ingresa la clave de la materia a eliminar y has click en eliminar</p>
        Clave <input type="text" name="clave">
        <input type="submit" value="Eliminar">
    </form>
    <table>
    <tr><th>Clave</th><th>Semestre</th><th>Especialidad</th><th>Horas</th></tr>
    <?php
        $jsonfile="materias.json";
        $materias=array();
        $content=file_get_contents($jsonfile);
        $materias=json_decode($content);
        $def=0;
        $varCount=count($materias);
        while($def<=$varCount){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->key;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->semester;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->specialty;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->hours;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $def++;
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <a href="/060522/menu.html">Volver</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo, puse una fila y una celda justo como muestro abajo y esa si la imprimia.

```php
    $varCount=count($materias);
    while($def<=$varCount){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Hola a todos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->key;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->semester;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->specialty;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $materias[$def]->hours;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $def++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
<a href="/060522/menu.html">Volver</a>
```

Contenido de materias.json

```json
{
    "0":{"key":"9748026452","semester":"4","specialty":"Contabilidad","hours":"5"},
    "1":{"key":"4376197623","semester":"4","specialty":"Mecanica","hours":"4"},
    "2":{"key":"5637945638","semester":"4","specialty":"Contabilidad","hours":"5"},
    "3":{"key":"4678415905","semester":"6","specialty":"Programacion","hours":"12"},
    "4":{"key":"6130620013","semester":"6","specialty":"Mecanica","hours":"3"},
    "5":{"key":"6130620013","semester":"6","specialty":"Mecanica","hours":"3"},
    "6":{"key":"0907200134","semester":"3","specialty":"Laboratorista Clinico","hours":"4"},
    "7":{"key":"0702200209","semester":"2","specialty":"Mecanica","hours":"4"},
    "8":{"key":"4563856123","semester":"5","specialty":"Administracion","hours":"10"},
    "9":{"key":"0861595377","semester":"2","specialty":"Administracion","hours":"7"},
    "10":{"key":"8748638724","semester":"4","specialty":"Mecanica","hours":"6"},
    "11":{"key":"563931287","semester":"4","specialty":"Administracion","hours":"9"},
    "12":{"key":"6537821230","semester":"5","specialty":"Programacion","hours":"10"},
    "14":{"key":"9823756738","semester":"4","specialty":"Mecanica","hours":"8"},
    "15":{"key":"9230984792","semester":"1","specialty":"Administracion","hours":"6"},
    "16":{"key":"0586573084","semester":"5","specialty":"Programacion","hours":"4"},
    "17":{"key":"3102603106","semester":"3","specialty":"Contabilidad","hours":"7"},
    "18":{"key":"8749386590","semester":"4","specialty":"Laboratorista Clinico","hours":"6"},
    "19":{"key":"7484300027","semester":"5","specialty":"Contabilidad","hours":"12"}
}
```

Me he dado cuenta de algo mas, si mi archivo JSON esta de la siguiente manera LA TABLA SI PUEDE IMPRIMIRSE

```json
[
    {"key":"9748026452","semester":"4","specialty":"Contabilidad","hours":"5"},
    {"key":"4376197623","semester":"4","specialty":"Mecanica","hours":"4"}
]
```

Como pudieron notar, arriba tengo un input text y un input submit, se supone que al ingresar la clave de la materia y dar en eliminar, se eliminará toda la información de dicha materia.

```php
    <?php
    $clave=$_POST['clave'];
    $jsonfile="materias.json";
    $delete=array();
    $content=file_get_contents($jsonfile);
    $delete=json_decode($content);
    $abc=0;
    $varCount=count($delete);
    while($abc<=$varCount){
        if(($delete[$abc]->key)==$clave){
            unset($delete[$abc]);
            echo"all delete";
        }
        $abc++;
    }
    file_put_contents($jsonfile, json_encode($delete));
    ?>
```

Es después de dar click en eliminar que ocurre ese cambio en mi JSON.

¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Comment: ¿Podrías presionar [edit] y agregar en tu pregunta el contenido del archivo `materias.json`?

Comment: @Marcos Listo, he agregado el contenido de materias.json

Comment: Revisa el log de php. También inspecciona la salida con las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador. Haz un `var_dump`  a `$materias[$def]`.

Comment: @sweeの, el problema lo esta provocando cuando lees el archivo para borrar la materia. Tenés que hacerlo así `$delete=json_decode($content, true);`

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema es que `json_decode()` si no se le especifica, devuelve un objeto `object(stdClass)`. Ver [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode). Este objeto no se le puede aplicar `count()`.

Si vas a trabajarlo en forma de objeto, entonces debes hacer las siguientes modificaciones en el primer código:

```php
// ...
        $content=file_get_contents($jsonfile);
        $materias=json_decode($content);
        foreach($materias as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->key;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->semester;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->specialty;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->hours;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
// ...
```

Si, por el contrario, quieres trabajarlo como asociativo, podrías usar el `while` como lo planteas, pero no te va a funcionar, porque `$def++` se incrementa en orden, y hay índices numéricos que no aparecen en el JSON, como el **13**.
Para evitar ese problema, sugiero hacerlo así:

```php
// ...
        $content=file_get_contents($jsonfile);
        $materias=json_decode($content, true); // <-- true: devolver un array
        // $varCount=count($materias); // <-- Aqui funciona, pero no es necesario
        foreach($materias as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['key'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['semester'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['specialty'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['hours'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
// ...
```